# Create a new usermeta field for users

Tags: php, conditional-content, user-meta

How do I create a new usermeta field with a drop down selection values?

Im want to create a conditional statement for all users with a certain value of the new custom field I want.

For example,

The new field would be: Approved
The drop down values are: Yes and No

The conditional statement will recognize all users with the Approved field value of Yes. Then it will post a code.

Im working with the wp_get_current_user function(), which does exactly what I need, but I just need a new custom usermeta field. In the example the new usermeta field would be "artwork_approved."

Example:

```
wp_get_current_user();
if ($current_user->artwork_approved == 'Yes'){
    echo 'Thank you for approving your artwork!';
}
```

There seems to be no plugin for this and I *really* need this feature. I would really appreciate some advice on creating a new usermeta with drop down options.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook [edit_user_profile](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile) to add your custom inputs.

Then, you need to hook the [profile_update](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/profile_update) action and use the function [add_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) to add the metadata

Comment: That's what it boils down to. Here's a good tutorial showing those hooks in action: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

Comment: I found this great plugin that lets you create new usermeta fields, Register Plus Redux. It does exactly what I need. Thanks for the feedback!